# Correct way to develope a free and paid version of an app

Tags: android, android-build-flavors, android-flavors

I have an application that has free features and paid features.

Let's suppose that an activity, in **free** version can perform operation A, operation B, and has a disclaimer that in order to unlock operation C, user must purchase the full version. This activit has also ads.

The same activity, in **paid** version, has the same operation A, same operation B and of course the operation C unlocked. This activity has no ads.

Now, I've read that the correct way to manage a free and a paid version of an app is to create 2 flavors, in order to have a structure similar to this one:
[image: flavors structure]

where in main I put the "shared" parts of my app, and then I put the only-free parts in the "free" flavor, and the only-paid parts in "paid" flavor. 
But what about the activity described before? How can I share this activity (and it's functionality) between the two flavors, and showing or not the operation C and ads, depending on which version of my app is installed? 
I don't think (and don't see the point) that I need to put this activity in both  free and paid version, since I don't want to write 2 times my code when I will add code of that activity, but, instead, share code that is present in both 2 versions.

While of course I will put the only-paid features in the paid version.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
if(BuildConfig.Flavor.equals("free")) {
    //do something
}
else if(BuildConfig.Flavor.equals("paid")) {
   //do other thing
}
```

and press `ctrl + shift + f` to search the `BuildConfig.java` file, you will see this file structure.

Comment: And what about layout parts? I mean, if I need to show them only in paid version. Do I need to manage them in code, like by inflating them in an if statement like that?

Comment: Each flavor has its own res sub folder like under main